# How do I get large numbers of specific users cheaply?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing

I need to recruit 100 users for a quantitative survey. The users need to have specific job roles in sales and marketing. While an even split in demographics is ideal, it is not required.

I have the constraints of a small budget and little time (we don't have a full-time user researcher).

What are the best method(s) to fulfill this need given these constraints?

Comment: By specific users - the survey will only be open to users with specific job roles.

Comment: Moderators-Thank you for reviewing the question. In the UX world, I feel that this is a legitimate question that small orgs face and would ask you to reconsider. If you have a recommendation on how to reword, please give such constructive  feedback.  Already, I did not know about Instant.ly or Verifyapp so this was very useful to me and potentially to others. Expertise and references do come into play as folks have done this numerous times have developed concrete strategies and best practices and/or worked with certain service providers to achieve such consistent  and successful results.

Comment: I decided against voting to close this question, but it was a close case.  My hunch is that people voted to close it for two reasons. Reason 1: [Product requests](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are often closed on the UX StackExchange because they tend not to be a great fit for a Q&A site. (They have no one correct answer and quickly become outdated.)

Comment: Reason 2: [Requests for subjectively "best" lists, ideas, ways, or suggestions](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/1313/21954) (or really anything plural) tend to have too many correct answers to work well with the site format that expects one correct answer to get voted to the top.

Comment: If you phrase your question to ask about a specific problem you're having when recruiting users, then {1} good answers may mention products, but the product won't be the full content of the answer and {2} the response will naturally be what it's poster thinks is best for that specific context, but will not prompt a debate of what is "best" without a context.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open your question because it has a reasonably-scoped context of a real-world problem, recruiting a given number of users for a specific type of study with limited time and money.  You can strengthen your post (and help it get re-opened) by adding additional context, such as the role of user you need to recruit (e.g. recruiting doctors is a fair bit different from recruiting parents; people who are familiar with your site give very different feedback than people who are not) and how much time the study requires (a 1 minute survey is quite different from a 30-minute survey).

Comment: Thank you Graham for you valuable additional info. I am adding additional context now

Comment: Voting to re-open.   It's a very tangible practical UX problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a sales business, contact your sales staff. They can probably put you in touch with customers or provide lists of customers. Tread carefully as you approach your customers for help, so you don't come across as spam.

If you're doing usability testing, you can try a service that does remote usability testing. [UserTesting.com](https://www.usertesting.com/) does this.

Answer (score 2):

A survey tool like Instant.ly or Survey Monkey has huge panels of survey takers that you can segment by demographics and more, usually pretty cheap around a dollar or two per head. Another one with more tech-related options is Verifyapp.